# What are the criteria for when siri speaks a response on the watch?

Tags: apple-watch, siri

iphone 8 running IOS 13.1.2, watch 4 running 6.0.1

If I push the crown and ask "is it going to rain today" I get a graphical response of the "weather circle" set to the precipitation percentage, but no spoken response.

If I push the crown and ask what's the forecast for today" I get the same weather circle, but set to cloud coverage with the temperature in the middle, and a spoken response of "here's the forecast for today"

If I push the crown and ask "is it going to rain tomorrow" it says "sure looks like it's going to rain" and I get the 10 day graphical forecast.

I don't recall what the behavior was in past versions since I didn't really use siri a lot.

How do I get it to say "yes, it's going to rain today" or "looks like clear skies today" or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone and Mac, "Will it rain today" prompts, "It doesn't look like it is going to rain today" with the weather chart.

Siri help says, "Should I bring umbrella today?"